# Running the same JS function on multiple <input> name values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

Hello guys and thanks for helping out in the first place!

I'm running into some trouble with checkboxes and .js since it's the first time i'm using those.

I'll provide a fiddle so you can see the problem.

I have a .js function which works with "input name=" to display a certain div when multiple checkboxes are selected and everything is working fine.

The problem is, i want to group my checkboxes in different categories, to later on having the possibility of having only one checkbox for each category selected at a time.

Changing the "name=" value seems like the smartest and easiest thing but as soon as i change that, in both .js and html file, everything stops working.

So the question is: how can i replicate my .js function using different name values?

example: first category is "colors" and they will all be named as "cc",
second category will be "rims" and they will all be named "bb", third category is "pads" and they will all be named "aa"

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q98pvLk0/

html:

```
    <div id="configurations">
<div id="colorbuttons">
  <h1>Colors</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yellow" name="cc" value="yellow_div_id" data-ref="yellow_div_id" />
  <label>Yellow</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="cc" value="green_div_id" data-ref="green_div_id" />
  <label>Green</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="cc" value="red_div_id" data-ref="red_div_id" />
  <label>Red</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="cc" value="blue_div_id" data-ref="blue_div_id" />
  <label>Blue</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="cc" value="orange_div_id" data-ref="orange_div_id" />
  <label>Orange</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="purple" name="cc" value="purple_div_id" data-ref="purple_div_id" />
  <label>Purple</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lightblue" name="cc" value="lightblue_div_id" data-ref="lightblue_div_id" />
  <label>Light Blue</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="magenta" name="cc" value="magenta_div_id" data-ref="magenta_div_id" />
  <label>Magenta</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="aubergine" name="cc" value="aubergine_div_id" data-ref="aubergine_div_id" />
  <label>Aubergine</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="turquoise" name="cc" value="turquoise_div_id" data-ref="turquoise_div_id" />
  <label>Turquoise</label>
</div>
<div id="rimsbuttons">
  <h1>Rims</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cerchio1" name="cc" value="cerchio1_div_id" data-ref="cerchio1_div_id" />
  <label>Cerchio 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cerchio2" name="cc" value="cerchio2_div_id" data-ref="cerchio2_div_id" />
  <label>Cerchio 2</label>
</div>
<div id="padsbuttons">
  <h1>Pads</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="pinza1" name="cc" value="pinza1_div_id" data-ref="pinza1_div_id" />
  <label>Pinza 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="pinza2" name="cc" value="pinza2_div_id" data-ref="pinza2_div_id" />
  <label>Pinza 2</label>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Loaded/hidden content div-->
<div id="listings">
 <div class="hide-me" id="default">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/default_1_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_1_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_1_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="defaultcerchio2pinza1_div_id">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/default_2_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_2_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_2_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="defaultcerchio2pinza2_div_id">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/default_1_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_1_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_1_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="defaultcerchio1">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/default_2_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_2_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/default_2_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="yellowcerchio1pinza1_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="yellowcerchio1pinza2_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_1_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="yellowcerchio2pinza2_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="yellowcerchio2pinza1_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/yellow_2_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="orangecerchio1pinza1_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="orangecerchio2pinza1_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_1_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_1_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_1_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="orangecerchio2pinza2_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_2_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="hide-me" id="orangecerchio1pinza2_div_id" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="rslides">
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_2_view1.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_2_view2.png" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="img/orange_1_2_view3.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select checkboxes by name
    var packages = $("input[name='cc']");
    // set main div id
    var packageDiv = $("#listings");

    // bind to change event
    packages.change(function () {

        // empty array
        var idArr = [];
        // get the checked values
        var checked = $("input[name='cc']:checked");
        // loop and build array
        checked.each(function () {
            idArr.push($(this).prop("id"));
        });

        // remove whitespace from multiple checkboxes array
        var trimArray = idArr.join("");

        toggleShowHide(trimArray, packageDiv);

    });

});

function toggleShowHide(arr, elem) {

    var arrLen = arr.length;

    // clear last selection when unchecking boxes
    $(".hide-me").hide();

    // set default if array is empty
    if (arrLen < 1 ){
        setDefault(elem);
    }

    // run the show hide based on array of selection

    for(i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        // set the name for the selected div
        var temp = "#" + arr + "_div_id";

        $(temp).show();
        $("#default").hide();

    }

    // unhide
    elem.show();

}

function setDefault(elem){
    $("#default").show();
}

//SLIDESHOW

  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto:false,
      nav:true,
    });
  });
```

css:

```
#configurations{
  float: left;
  width:20vw;
}
#colorbuttons{
  float: left;
  width:20vw;
}

#rimsbuttons{
  float: left;
  width:20vw;
}

#padsbuttons{
  position:float;
  float: left;
  width:20vw;
}

#listings{
  position:float;
  float: left;
  width:80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

Comment: _"having only one checkbox for each category selected at a time"_, if you only want one input out of a certain group of inputs to be selectable use radio inputs instead of checkboxes

Comment: Problem with this would be creating groups of radio buttons, and that is the main problem, if I create a radio group using another name other than “cc” the js stops working, I’m missing the knowledge to adapt the .js function to other names

Comment: I'd add a class name defining a checkbox's group and then you can select only one based on that. Or debug/determine why the "cc" stops working.

Comment: I’m trying to determine why when I change my js target from “cc” to something else stops working, that’s where I need your help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, i just needed to group radio buttons in different divs using the "form" tag, with this tag i can keep the "cc" name on every input but having them in different groups at the same time, thank you for all the answers!